# Multiple classes in body tag, multi-dimensional css structure or blueprint for insanity?

Tags: css, css-selectors

This question is about an approach to css structuring, and so is more discussion oriented.

I'm working with some outsourced css where the body tags have multiple classes assigned, up to half a dozen. (To make things a little worse, none of the css selectors include an html tag which is making it confusing to analyze the css.) These body classes are then used to modify classed or id'd widgets within.

It seems like this approach is like adding an additional dimension to the css, perhaps in some attempt to create a structured css approach. Documentation might have helped, had we been provided any.

This differs from my approach where widgets are styled primarily via id'd divs, perhaps extracting the more generic elements into a class, i.e. div#MyWidget.widgets.

Any ideas on whether such an approach is maintainable, especially considering I am dealing with websites with thousands of pages including tons of legacy stuff, all done by different people with different skill levels? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I find nothing particularly wrong with this approach, provided you are conceptually using the body tags to apply very general style rules.  The higher up the class is in the DOM, the more generic it should be.

It's hard to answer specifically without examples.  One I frequently use is to turn the URL segments into classes for body tag in my pages, for relatively small sites:

```
// mysite.com/users/show/
<body class="users show">
  <div id="Content">
     ...
  </div>
</body>
```

I use this almost exclusively for overriding default styles on very specific pages:

```
#Content {
  width:500px;
}

.users.show #Content {
  width:600px;
}
```